# Particular 6-regular graph on 42 vertices.

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

Does anybody know of the existence of any known graphs that are 6-regular on 42 vertices?

Comment: It would improve your Question to add some context.  Why is this of interest to you?  What did you try, and what difficulty did you encounter?  Such material will help Readers respond in a manner most likely to be useful to you (and to later Readers).

Comment: The Erdos-Gallai theorem shows immediately that such a graph exists, no?

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez:  Well, easily if not immediately.  [The theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erd%C5%91s%E2%80%93Gallai_theorem) asks us to check a number of inequalities, $1\le k \le 42$.  The ones for $k \gt 6$ can be dismissed "by inspection", and the ones for $k=1,2,\ldots,6$ are easily checked.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let us consider the $42$ vertices arranged in a circle.  Let each vertex be connected to the three consecutive vertices preceding it and to the three consecutive vertices following it.

Since there are enough vertices to prevent these edges from "wrapping around" the circle, the edges are well-defined.  The graph is $6$-regular.

**Added:** To make the problem more interesting, I'll describe two solutions that potentially are different from the one above.

First consider six disjoint copies of $K_7$, the complete graph on seven vertices.  Clearly this has $42$ nodes in all, and each node has degree six.

Second consider a periodic triangulation of the plane:

[image: periodic triangulation]

Make the graph finite by lattice periodicity, identifying every seventh node along the direction indicated by right pointing arrow and every sixth node along the direction of the arrow going up.  Again we have $42$ vertices in all, each with degree six.

The challenge for the interested Reader is to determine whether the three solutions are different (not graph isomorphic).

Hint:

> Consider the six neighbors of a fixed vertex, and count the edges between them.

Comment: +1. In general, the same construction shows there exist $2k$-regular graphs of any size $n \ge 2k+1$.

Comment: This graph can be concisely expressed as $C_{42}^3$, the cycle cubed.

Comment: There are so many different graphs that meet these requirements that the minds wants something additional to focus on.  Even restricting ourselves to vertex transitive graphs, there are still many solutions.